# Subversion: possible to pick which files you can stage for commit?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm working on a project that is being versioned with svn. Normally with git, I would pick which files I'd like to make as part of a commit with git add, and then make a commit. The problem is, I don't know if there  is a similar way to do something like that in subversion. I end up working on a feature, then get interrupted to fix a bug.. and end up having to commit both of them at once. Is there a smarter way to handle staging of commits so my bug fix and feature can be separate commits in svn? I don't want to branch either, because that's god awful in subversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options:

- Manually choose to only commit the files that you're interested in.  `svn commit file1 file2 ...`, or use a 
  client like TortoiseSVN that provides a GUI for doing so.
- Use [changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.changelists.html).

(Really, in recent versions of Subversion and with a good client like Tortoise, I don't think branching is as awful as it's made out to be, but that's another story...)

Comment: Using TortoiseSVN (http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), when you commit, you're presented with a list of all changed files, each with a checkbox. You simply click off the checkbox next to each file you don't want included.

Answer (score 0):

[git-svn bridge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Branching is super easy in Subversion. Any problems come when you merge the changes back, but that's often the same story with any SCM, even git, when you try merging binaries or resolving conflicts.